# Jquery function - checkbox with same name

Tags: jquery

I have about 20 checkboxes with same name, but id values is not the same

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="1_2"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="10_4"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="5_6"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="4_0"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="8_9"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="device" id="3_4"/>
```

I want a function, if i click on a checkbox, then i get a alert with the value of ID

Example, if i click on the first checkbox

```
alert("Value before _ : 1 - Value after _ : 2")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you shouldn't have checkboxes with same value for name attribute. You'll only get one checkbox's value when the form is posted.

Comment: You want to show the deselected value, then the new value?

Comment: `alert("Value before _ : 1 - Value after _ : 2")` what is required here? and what is `1 and 2` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz4En/)

Hope its what you need, have fun playing with it.

**HTML**: (add a class to the inputs)

```
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="1_2"/>
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="10_4"/>
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="5_6"/>
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="4_0"/>
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="8_9"/>
 <input class='try' type="checkbox" name="device" id="3_4"/>
```

**SCRIPT**: (click event)

```
$('.try').click(function() {
    var idd= $(this).attr('id');
    var explode = idd.split('_');
    alert('Value before:' + explode[0] + ' - Value after:' + explode[1]);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id').split('_');` its quite good one but `this.id.split('_');` is far better.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
           var vals = this.id.split('_');
           alert("Value before _ : "+vals[0]+" - Value after _ : " + vals[1])
        })
     })
```

This function is called on click of each checkbox. It uses javascript's [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to *split* the id attribute value into an array.

Comment: That's great @KevinLund . You could mark the most helpful answer as _the answer_ by clicking the tick mark beside it. It'll be helpful for future visitors and for you to get best answers in future.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need.?
<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcqds/)</kbd>

```
    $('input:checkbox[name="device"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert( 'Value before:' + id.split('_')[0] + ' - Value after:' + id.split('_')[1] );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
   arr = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
   alert("Value before _ :"+arr[0]+" Value after _ :"+arr[1]);
});
```

here is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Beck/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
     alert($(this).attr("id"))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
     $('input:checkbox[name="device"]').click( function(){ 
         var selected_data = $(this).attr('id').split('_'); 
         alert('Value before _ : ' + selected_data[0] + ' - ' + 'Value after _ : ' +      selected_data[1]);
     });
```

Comment: This piece of code will only select the check box which has name "device". Even if you have any others checkboxes for any purpose then it wont effect. Enjoy coding !!!!